# Deploy Grails Application on Amazon EC2

Tags: tomcat, grails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have developed Grails app and successfully deployed it on Tomcat7 windows version. I wanted to deploy it on Amazon EC2 (AMI linux 32 version). I installed Tomcat7 on EC2 successfully and everything worked well. I transferred the .war file to amazon ec2 but I got error message that "http status 404: The requested resource is not available". I am wondering if the mismatch between generate .war file in windows and Linux is the source of problem? any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe, there are some error when Tomcat try to deploy your .war file. Take a look in catalina.out to see if there is any message when you copy the .war file to the webapps directory on the EC2 instance.

By the way, are there any reason to use 32-bit AMI rather then 64-bit? I think all EC2 instance types support 64-bit OS.

Comment: Thanks Raymomd. I try to deploy on 64-bit to see if it works while my windows version for development was 64!

Comment: maybe my previous comment is confusing, but I don't mean the 64-bit vs 32-bit is the source of the problem. Reading Tomcat server log (catalina.out) should provide more information on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into using [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) for deployment? EC2 itself is more of an IAAS so you still have to handle a lot of config details (e.g. server install, load balancing..), which can be difficult. Beanstalk is a free wrapper (e.g. PAAS) around most of the AWS services you would need in a typical installation with some pre-configured environments ready for your deployment.

Here's an [article on how to deploy Grails](http://www.bobbywarner.com/2011/10/14/grails-on-aws/) using Beanstalk - it's a little old but still very relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Boxfuse comes with dead easy native support [deploying Grails 3.x apps on EC2](https://boxfuse.com/blog/grails-aws).

All you need to do is literally

```
boxfuse run my-grails3-app-1.0.jar
```

and Boxfuse will automatically

- fuse a minimal OS image tailor-made for your app (takes <10 seconds, image around 100 MB *including* the JVM & your app)
- push it to a secure online image repository
- convert it to an AMI in about 30 seconds
- create an elastic IP and assign a new domain to it
- create a security group with the correct ports open
- launch an instance of your AMI & make sure the healthchecks pass
- map the elastic ip (and the new domain) to your new instance

All updates are performed as **zero-downtime blue/green deployments**. And if you need more than one instance Boxfuse also supports ELBs, Auto-scaling and more.

Boxfuse analyses your native Grails 3 application.yml config and automatically extracts the ports and healthcheck information required for your app. This information is then used to correctly set up security groups and ELBs.

More info: https://boxfuse.com/getstarted/grails

*Disclaimer: I am the founder and CEO of Boxfuse*

Answer (score 0):

This can be a problem of path mapping. You can try installing the web app as the root and give it a try.