# Install a Grails War File to remote server including mysql database

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I have a Grails War File that includes a game application. Also I have the mysql database for this game.
I have never before engaged with Grails.  I want to install this application to a remote server. I found some information for start, So until now I know:
1. I need a hoster supports Java Virtual machine. (I found that amazon web services fulfill this requirement). They have TomCat as operating system.
http://grails.org/Deployment
2. I should install there a Grails Distribution. http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#requirements
 3.Upload with ftp the war file and install it. I am a little confused on how to install  the application on the remote server.
4. Install database and connect it with the application.

is there any manual for doing this? I have search but I can’t find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using AWS, see this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945176/deploy-grails-application-on-amazon-ec2/16947096#16947096). Basically you'll want to use elastic beanstalk to ease deployment and environment creation (i.e, you don't have to install any software/server, just a couple of configurations settings, and upload your code). Here's a related article

http://www.bobbywarner.com/2011/10/14/grails-on-aws/

Comment: Thank you very helpful links. I am start working on upload it. I will post you comment if i have trouble. Thank you.

Comment: Hello! I have install the application on TomCat 7 enviroment Elastic Beanstalk wizard. The aplication uploaded as a zip. I get error: The requested resource (/) is not available. HTTP Status 404

Comment: From your beanstalk dashboard view, select your environment details -> logs tab -> snapshot of logs. Do you see any errors? Another thing to look at is your security: from your ec2 dashboard view, select your instance -> the details should display on bottom pane -> look for security groups -> rules. You should see a green check mark for port 80 rule

Answer (score 1):

deploying war is just a matter of putting the .war file in web-apps folder of Tomcat
regarding database, it depends that kind of database you use locally - if mysql/postres/etc., you have to install it on the host server (how to do it, depends both on database type and operating system installed on the server) - or it can be file or in-memory h2 database, but this isn't good for production I suppose

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So i have to upload with ftp the file / run the sql script to the mysql(create the db)/ change the connection string on the aplication (web config... i will find the corresponding file)/ and then i have app online? Am i correct?

Comment: ideally, yes :) please note, that you should now use "production" environment configuration both in Config.groovy and Datasource.groovy since you deploy a war

Answer (score 0):

I am only familiar with ordinary Linux VPS or dedicated server, not with cloud.  This is what I will do.

- Install MySQL and Tomcat on server.  You may use ordinary user for Tomcat if you wish.  E.g. extract tomcat zip file in /home/focus/tomcat7
- Create the schema in server

  $ mysql -u root -ppassword

  mysql> create schema mydb;
- Upload your sql dump to the server and restore

  $ mysql -u root -ppassword mydb < dbdump.sql
- Create JNDI resource in Tomcat.  E.g. edit /home/focus/tomcat7/conf/context.xml and add resource in context:

> ```
> <Context>
>     <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
>     <Resource name="myDatasourceName" auth="Container" 
>      type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" 
>      maxWait="10000" username="root" password="password"  
>      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
>      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/> 
> </Context>
> ```

- Add JNDI resource in production portion of your DataSource.groovy

> ```
> ...
> environments {
> ...
>     production {
>         dataSource {
>             dbCreate = "update"
>             jndiName = "java:comp/env/myDatasourceName
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

- create war and upload to /home/focus/tomcat7/webapps